# Onlive using wine the raw input

Tags: wine, patch, input

I've been doing a great deal of searching for the past few days for this.

I used to be able to play onlive games with wine. (With a few tweaks here and there. (I think.)) 
But the problem now is that Wine is not taking my raw input from my mouse/keyboard.

I found a few patches that may work, but im very **VERY** new to all of this "patching and compiling" nonsense.

So all in all, I'm lost. Help!

Comment: So.. what exactly are you aksing for?.

Comment: Am with Uri. What are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its much easier with Playonlinux.  Then you don't have to compile wine versions.  Try this

1) Download and install Playonlinux make sure you get latest version 4.0.12 see the download page for your distro at playonlinux.com

2) Launch Playonlinux  click install select internet exlorer

3) Run internet explorer then go to Onlive, signup and download setup file to desktop

4) Open Playonlinux again, select tools, then select 'manage wine versions' install version 1.3.27 rawinput on x86 and amd64 then close that window

5) On the main Playonlinux window  lick at bottom of window "Install a non-listed program"

6) Click next

7) Make sure option "Install a program in a new virtual drive" is selected and click next

8) Give it a name, e.g. "OnLive"

9) Select "Use another version of Wine" and click next

10) Select "wine 1.3.27 rawinput"

11) Browse to OnLive-Setup.exe

12) Install OnLive

13) Select the OnLive.exe, click next then type the shortcut, click next

14) Click "I don't want to make another shortcut"

And you're there :)

If you have audio problems try killing pulse audio process before launching onlive